# Can't get data out of variable

Tags: php, json, variables, curl

I've made a curl request. I put the curl instructions in one class function:

```
class Curly {
  var $data;

  function GetRequest($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $this->data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    //this is what i was missing --> return $this->data;
  }
```

I put the database query in another class function.

```
include('class.curly.php');

class mongoSearchForInfoOnEsd {
  public function getEsdsFbInfo($esdID) {
    $mongoApiKey = "xx";
    $requestParams= "xx";
    $url = "xx";

    $fbInfo = (new Curly)->GetRequest($url);
    //this is what i was missing --> return $fbInfo;
  }
```

In the index.php, an HTTP post from a webhook is coming through, in which parsing through some strings to obtain 2 ids is handled. I then send one of those ids to the mongodb curl request, everything goes good. The correct response comes back, I only know this b/c of the var_dump of the var_dump in the curly class....BUT in the index file I'm struggling to get to get the data out of the var and assign its values to any variable I want.

How can I get the data out? I know its there, but where?
I'm so stuck.

```
# get ytID from http post
#get EsdID from http post
$httpPostData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$postDataDecoded = urldecode($httpPostData);
$ytID = substr($postDataDecoded, strpos($postDataDecoded, "docid=") + strlen("docid="), );
$esdID = substr($postDataDecoded, strpos($postDataDecoded, "m\": \"") + strlen    ("m\": "),;
*$esdData = (new mongoSearchForInfoOnEsd)->getEsdsFbInfo("$esdID");*
$obj = json_decode($esdData, true);
echo $obj;
```

OK, I've added return and I can see the data, but no operations are working on returned data.

edit ---> put return in both classes, now its fully operational.

Comment: Maybe you need `return` in your `GetRequest()` ?

Comment: That's exactly what I was just going to say ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lazyhammer said you need to write the following in the end of your method GetRequest($url)

```
return $this->data;
```

Also, in a class, a `function` is called a `method`.

To be more explicit.

`var_dump` doesn't return the data. it's only sending them to the client(your browser) which will display it.

to return the data computed in your method back to the caller, you need to use the keyword `return` at the end of your method.
When your computer will see `return` he bring back the data to the caller. it means everything you write after `return` won't be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you are assigning a value to the class variable `data` doesn't mean that value is being returned when you call the function getRequest. Therefore, in order to use the data from an outside class, you need to `return` the final value:

```
function GetRequest($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $this->data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $this->data;
}
```

You may not even need to keep the variable `$data` around, unless there is more to your code that you are not showing, you could simply return `curl_exec($ch)`

To further answer your question from your comments below, this is from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php):

> This function displays structured information about one or more expressions that includes its type and value. Arrays and objects are explored recursively with values indented to show structure.

As you can see, `var_dump` is used for *display purposes* only.

Comment: so why when i execute the index.php script, i can see the data being returned from the var_dump? it's just teasing me and not letting me actually play with it??

Comment: var_dump simply (as the name suggests) dumps the data being stored in your class variable called `data`. However, in order to send this data to the class from which the function was called, you need to `return` it.

Comment: `var_dump` is usually used for debugging purposes more than anything, so that you may see what data is stored in certain arrays or variables.

Comment: I tried to do an operation on the returned data and the same effect is happening Nuttin

Comment: GOT IT! @micka explained it to me the best. i needed return in both classes. but evan thank you for clarify var_dump for me aswell. Cheers to all.

Comment: ... I'm not sure what he explained that I didn't, but glad you got it figured out.